# Include a bash function into the parent script

Tags: bash, shell, function

I can to define function in bash and use it:

```
foo() { echo $1; }
foo test
```

But if I want to collect my functions in one bash script all its unavailable:

init.bash

```
#!/bin/bash
foo() { echo $1; }  
export -f foo # This not helps
```

Using:

```
./init.bash && foo test # error here
```

Is there any way to export script's functions to parent scope?
Without writing to `.bashrc`, it's too global
Same as `.bashrc` but for current bash instance only...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `source` the file `init.sh`.  No need to `export` the function in that file.

```
$ cat init.bash 
foo() { echo $1; }
```

And use it:

```
$ . ./init.bash && foo test
test
```

Sourcing a file would execute commands from it in the current shell context.  As such, the functions would be available in the *parent*.

`export` would set the attribute for a variable that would be applicable for the current shell and subshells.  Not the parent shell.  You need to define the variable in the *current* shell context.